# Docusign signing document without an account

Tags: java, docusignapi

I generate PDF in my application and I should send that PDF to specific person(email id) for e-signature. I use DocuSign Sandbox Dev environment. The recipient gets an email notification for reviewing the document and signing it. When he opens the document, it asks for an account for the recipient.

Is it possible that the recipient directly opens the document and sign it whoever it may be using the Sandbox account? Is there any solution for it to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to sign the document without an account.

You can set the appropriate level of security settings in your accountusing the [docusign admin console](https://admindemo.docusign.com/security-settings)

More information [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-security-settings). See the **Authentication Settings** section